# How can I check the time response of my model in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3dx, time, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users!

I would like to know the time response of my model P3DX in Gazebo.
I am going to explain it:

I am using ROS indigo, Gazebo2 and linux 14.04. I have a model P3DX (ua_p3dx_pkg). When I sent a linear velocity of 1m/s for example I wonder long does it take to reach that velocity my model. Maybe 0.2sec or samethink like that.

Is there any way to know that?

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207285/how-can-i-check-the-time-response-of-my-model-in-gazebo?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Gazebo publishes the pose and the twist of every link on /gazebo/link_states topic.
You should be able to plot the velocity of a given link using this message.

To know the index of the link you want to monitor you can check its index in the list /gazebo/link_states/name
Then you can plot /gazebo/link_states/twist[INDEX_YOU_FOUND].

I don't know how often this message is published but it should allow you to monitor your twist and thus know how long it takes to reach the desired velocity.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-04-20**:
Thank you so much!!!